# Использование слова «наилучший»

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Стало очень интересно, ибо информации в интернете я не нашёл.

Comment: Очень интересно, ибо информация в интернете есть.

Answer (score 1):

Слово как таковое (в вопросе о "правильности" контекст не приводится) в словарях есть. Значение слова: *самый лучший из возможных или доступных для выбора* (чаще всего - о методе, решении; иногда о пожеланиях).

Answer (score 1):

**НАИЛУ́ЧШИЙ**, наилучшая, наилучшее (книжн.).
Самый лучший, самый предпочтительный, представляющий преимущества сравнительно с другими. *Наилучший способ. Наилучший сорт.*
[**Толковый словарь Ушакова**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/870690/%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%A3%D0%A7%D0%A8%D0%98%D0%99)

**Наилучший** — прилагательное, мужской род, превосходная степень, качественное.
Частота употребления: 89 694 раза на ≈ 300 млн. слов.

*Можно считать, что **наилучший возраст** партизана — двадцать пять - тридцать лет. В этом возрасте человек уже достаточно созрел и определился.*
Э. Гевара. Опыт революционной борьбы

*Но взятую на себя работу я всегда стараюсь выполнить **наилучшим образом**, а не кое-как, лишь бы отделаться от нее*.
В. Обручев. За тайнами Плутона

*Я не стал продолжать этот разговор, поняв, что молчание в данном случае будет для меня **наилучшим выходом***.
А. Кристи. Двойной грех